# matplotlib stack bar grouped by date (month and year)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Consider the over simplified data frame that has 2 columns: Dates and Values.

```
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-01-05 02:00:00','2017-03-01 02:00:00', '2018-01-01 03:00:00', '2018-01-21 04:00:00','2018-03-01 03:00:00', '2018-03-22 04:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
my_df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":dates,"Values":[5,1,2,4,6,3,5]})
my_df
```

[image]

My objective is to **plot** a stack-bar in such way that the x_axis will have the month_year and the bar will show a stack of values.  For example for the month Jan-2017 I'd expect to see 2 colors with 5 and 1 sums up to 6 and so forth.

Since this is a group-by_date related issue, I was wondering how to get a list of values based on month-year so I can have them stacked properly together and later have a for loop such that:

```
for each month_year:
     plt.bar(month_year, list_of_values_per_month_year, color='#whatever',)
```

Note that not every month has a value and some month have n values.

Unless of course my approach is fundamentally complicated and there's a smoother way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create the `pivot` table , then `plot` stack bar

```
my_df.Date=my_df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
my_df['col']=my_df.groupby('Date').cumcount()
my_df.pivot(index='Date',columns='col',values='Values').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image]